# Moving containerView in superView as a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

following image describes the scenario.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPm4e.png

On animate button press, the blue screen (or containerView) should move away from view and similarly come back to initial position on repress.

The code is working. But the containerView is not behaving as the subview of some other view. It should not come out of light gray colored view. Which is its super view. It should move up and down within its limits.

The simulator screen shots are as follows :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJjA5.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I98W8.png

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

ViewController.m :-

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    BOOL scrollUp;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.containerBackgroundView addSubview:self.containerview];

    scrollUp = NO;
    [self animate:self];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}


- (IBAction)animate:(id)sender {

    if (scrollUp) {
        [self rollUpMenuPage];
        scrollUp = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        scrollUp = YES;
        [self unRollTheMenuPage];
    }

}

-(void)unRollTheMenuPage
{

    NSLog(@"containerview frame before unRoll : %@",[self.containerview description]);

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(self.containerview.frame.origin.x, 0.0f, self.containerview.frame.size.width, self.containerview.frame.size.height);


    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                     animations:^{

                         self.containerview.frame = rect;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         // do something here if you wish.

                         NSLog(@"containerview frame after unRoll : %@",[self.containerview description]);

                     }];

}

-(void)rollUpMenuPage
{

    NSLog(@"containerview frame before roll up : %@",[self.containerview description]);

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(self.containerview.frame.origin.x, -self.containerBackgroundView.frame.size.height, self.containerview.frame.size.width, self.containerview.frame.size.height);


    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                     animations:^{
                         self.containerview.frame = rect;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         NSLog(@"containerview frame after roll up : %@",[self.containerview description]);

                     }];


}
```

ViewController.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerBackgroundView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerview;
```

Current output :-
http://screencast.com/t/bfLmJFYmym4

Issue is, when moving up it should not go above the light gray colored view.

Thanks

Comment: Show the code you're using for animating

Comment: sorry I don't know how to add code

Comment: you have a sign of "{ }" above the text area, write any text and select it all and press the button "{ }"

Comment: What is the upper white view? is it a subView of containerBackgroundView?

Comment: @YuviGr No. It is not a subview. its a self.view

Comment: when you animate your container view try changing the bounds instead of the frame

Comment: @YuviGr , I tried changing the bounds but it is not working.

Comment: then you have a problem with your views hierarchy. You are setting the bounds's/frame's origin of the containerView to be (0,0) but the container goes to the self.view origin (0,0). That means that the superView of the containerView is self.view. Check that all of your views are placed in the right place in the view hierarchy

Comment: @YuviGr, Thanks, Sorry to bother you. I have updated my question with the screencast video to show the current output. Can you please check it.

Comment: lets go into chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70125/containerviewchat

Comment: check the " CGRect rect = CGRectMake(self.containerview.frame.origin.x, 0.0f, self.containerview.frame.size.width, self.containerview.frame.size.height); " - x position .

Comment: @YuviGr , Sorry I don't have enough reputation to talk . It need more than 20

Comment: @Vineesh TP, the x position is to allright. It is there to keep the horizontal offset constant while moving the containerView up and down.

Comment: np, are you using Autolayout?

Comment: @YuviGr, No I am not using autolayout.

Comment: @Ganesh: I mean just hard code the x position then , try again. Don't give ' self.containerview.frame.origin.x '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after re-creating your project and testing it you are right the view si drawn outside of it's superView bounds.

To undo this you can click the `clip subviews` property in the back view, so when the containerView steps out of the backView bounds it will be clipped and will not get drawn

Comment: he is not setting a negative value to the origin.y in the rectangle he builds there, so why would it move beyond the top of the other view?

Comment: i Believe "-self.containerBackgroundView.frame.size.height" is a negative value.

Comment: @YuviGr, Good morning, Yes "-self.containerBackgroundView.frame.size.height"  is a negative value just to make sure it moves up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have added a UINavigationBar (or some other toolBar) up top as a subview of your UIViewController's view, and that containerBackroundView (which is transparent bg colour) is over the top of that bar.
Suggest you alter the frame.origin.y of containerBackgroundView so that it does not cover that top bar there or go beneath the status bar.

Comment: Thanks, But I haven't added any navigation bar or anything at top. It consists just the single ViewController not even embedded in any navigation controller.

Comment: what is the white rectangle up top and underneath the status bar?
and the blue text def looks like a UINavigationItem..